# How to move the arrow markers 1 unit only?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm new to learning C#. How can I move an arrow one unit at a time?

[image: Project screenshot]

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class ArrowMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float directX;
    float directY;

    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 100;
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 100;

        Vector3 vel = rb.velocity;
        vel.x = h;
        vel.z = v;
        rb.velocity = vel;
    }
}
```

I just know how to do basic move

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your 3D models are in 1 unit scale as per unity.

`Input.GetAxis` will give you float values. Use `Input.GetKeyDown("Key")` instead.

Let's suppose you want to move up so you can use:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    transform.position += Vector3.Up;
}
```

`Vector3.Up` is Shorthand for writing Vector3(0, 1, 0) and 1 represent 1 unit. For more detail on representation of 3D vectors and points. click [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html).